# CSS: element with gradient background and wave border

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients, wave

Faced a problem that I can not solve in any way. I have an elite with a gradient fill and a wavy border. How can I implement it on the CSS?
The wavy border is at the top and bottom of the element. I highlighted this place in red, and also increased a piece of wavy border for clarity (left).
[Watch here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orhJB.png)

How do I make a gradient fill of an element on CSS so that this fill affects the wavy border? Thank you in advance for your cooperation!

For now, I'm just using background-image.

```
background-image: url($host + 'app/img/main/bonus-wave.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I was hoping that you will tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: `For now, I'm just using background-image.` --> show us what you are using then